# Reducing dimensions for supervised learning

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have this type of numpy array. Here i have shown 2 elements of the array. I have converted a .jpeg file to numpy array.

```
[[[130 130 130 ..., 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  [ 68  68  68 ...,  68  68  68]]

  [[130 130 130 ..., 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
  [ 68  68  68 ...,  68  68  68]]]
```

This numpy array has shape:(2, 243, 320). 
Now I want to do supervised learning on this array of features along with a label numpy array. But when i try to do that it says expected number of arguments <=3.

Now I tried reducing the dimensions by LDA as follows.

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(features, labels).transform(features)
```

But again it says that LDA expects <=2 dimensions. How do i reduce the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is simple, you are not sending the list in the required format.... The format which `.fit` requires is a 2 dimensional array. What you are sending is a 3 dimensional... There was no need of using dimensionality reduction because its totally a different issue...(for preventing overfitting to be specific)

So suppposing your array is name `arr`(ndarray)

just do this -

```
fin_array = arr.reshape((2*243, 320))
```

What this'll do is convert your array to a 2d list and woot now you can use it to fit the model!

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you so much. I am new to machine learning so my fundamentals are not that strong.

Answer (score 0):

Using reshape:

```
new_img = np.reshape(old_data,(2,243*320))
```

Comment: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged. 
This is the error when i tried this.

Comment: Try this: new_img = np.reshape(old_data,(2,243*320,1)) and then use squeeze to eliminate the last axis